# Explaning spike in query time after optimizing throughput of redis-server

Tags: redis

I optimized some calls I was making to my app's redis-server, significantly reducing the number of `expire` calls. See how the throughput went down:

[image]

But also notice how the query time abruptly went up (and the spikes became taller)! Why would that have happened?

I've essentially replaced `set` and `expire` pairs by `setex` in my code. I made one optimization around the 2:15AM, and then another around the 2:45AM mark. Notice how query time jumps up in the latter case only.

Is this simply a quirk of New Relic, or is there a Redis-centric explanation here? My overall aim was to keep both throughout and query time as low as possible. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you had 500 calls per minute, 400 fast and 100 slow type. The fast ones take 100ms, and slow ones take 500ms.
So newrelics will show average time as :

```
(400*100 + 100*500)/(400+100) = 180ms.
```

Now you combine some calls, and mostly the cheaper calls get eliminated from the previous setup, the new distribution is say 0 fast calls, and 100 slower calls.

```
(0*100 + 100*500)/(0+100)  = 500ms.
```

This is exactly what NewRelic is showing you, the expire calls were fast calls and were reducing the average.
What you shall be interested in is overall time i.e. `calls per minute*average time per call`, where you have surely benefited.